# how can i convert list to scapy.plist.PacketList in py3 code?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, pcap

i use `pkts = rdpcap('./xxx.pcap')` to recieve pkts in `xxx.pcap`, as i expect, it's type should be `scapy.plist.Packet`, but after rd, it was convert to `list` type, while list element can't be transfered as `pkts[IP]`, my code is as follows:

```
print(type(pkts))
myfunc(pkts)
```

and myfunc is like follows:

```
def myfunc(pkts, src_ip):
    if src_ip is not None:
        print(pkts[0].show())

        try: 
            pkts = pkts[IP].filter(lambda  x:x[IP].src in ipnet(src_ip))
        expect:
            raise TypeError
    return pkts
```

when i run, it raise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 89, in ip_filter
    pkts = pkts[IP].filter(lambda  x:x[IP].src in ipnet(src_ip))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Packet_metaclass
```

ipnet is equal to IPy.iP,

now, i know that i need to convert type of `list` to `scapy.plist.PacketList`, but how can i do that?

Comment: code start with ```pkts = rdpcap('xxx.pcap')```

Comment: `pkts[IP]` probably does something other than what you want. You can get the IP layer of a packet like `packet["IP"]` or get all IP layers in a group of packets by applying the same process iteratively: `[packet["IP"] for packet in pkts]`.

Comment: well, i use ```rdpcap()``` in ```func1```, and ```func1``` transfered  ```func2```, and give pkts as a par to ```func2```. like this: ```def func1: pkts=rdpcap('xxx.pcap')      func2(pkts)```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for Ross, i got it, cause python3 will reset the pkts's type from `scapy.plist.PacketList` to `list`, so we need to use scapy's `PacketList(pkts)` here, like this:

```
   def func2(pkts):
       pkts=PacketList(pkts)
       packet's process code.
   def func1():
       pkts=rdpcap('xxx.pcap')
       func2(pkts)
```

cause i'm not good at english, i don't know is it cleared what supscri**ed.